# Can the following code be editted, so that the second method is executed too?

Tags: c#

Is there anyway of calling methodB before methodA finishes, so that methodB gets executed? Ive tried numerous ways of implementing it, and none of them worked :(

---

can someone explain? Thanks.

```
public List<ObjectA> _OurObjectA= new List<ObjectA>();

public  List<ObjectA> methodA()
{

    List<ObjectA> products = new List<ObjectA>();
    ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = 
      new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
    client.getProductCompleted += 
      new EventHandler<ServiceReference1.getProductCompletedEventArgs>(methodB);

    client.getProductAsync();

    return _OurObjectA;
}

void methodB(object sender, ServiceReference1.getProductCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    ObservableCollection<ServiceReference1.ObjectA> products = e.Result;
    foreach (ServiceReference1.ObjectA obj in products)
    {
        ObjectA temp = new ObjectA(obj);
        _OurObjectA.Add(temp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It looks like methodA calls a web service.  When the web service is done it calls methodB.  The confusing part is that this is [asynchronous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O) (via the event handler)... methodA returns right away; it doesn't have to wait for the web service to finish.

This was probably done because the service takes a long time (relatively speaking), so in this case you can return from methodA right away, do some other work, and when the web service is done methodB can do it's stuff with the data returned from the web service.  This is a more efficient use of resources.  Sometimes this sort of thing is done so that the UI doesn't look like it's "hanging."

Comment: Thanks so much. Yes, this is a silverlight application with WCF service. MethodB never seems to get executed when I run this code, it just skips the part, and then the browser has an error, and the whole application, I guess this is because it is asynchronous? Is there anyway of fixing this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It assigns the method `methodB` as an event handler for the event `getProductCompleted`. When the event is raised by the `client` variable, the event handler is executed.

**UPDATE:**
I update my answer to actually answer your question...
You can use this code, to return from `methodA` after the products have been returned:

```
public  List<ObjectA> methodA()
{
    var products = new List<ObjectA>();
    var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    var client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
    client.getProductCompleted += (s, e) => {
                                               try
                                               {
                                                   products.AddRange(
                                                       e.Result.Select(o => 
                                                            new ObjectA(o)));
                                               }
                                               finally
                                               {
                                                   mre.Set();
                                               }
                                            };

    client.getProductAsync();
    mre.WaitOne();

    return products;
}
```

You don't even need methodB in that case.
The code assumes, you are using at least .NET 3.5.

Comment: Thanks for editing my code :) So I guess if methodA is called, then it automatically invokes methodB? But somehow, it is not called. Is there anyway of combining those 2 methods (into 1 method)? Thanks :)

Comment: methodB will only be called, when the event is raised. As Giovanni explains, this happens, after the webservice completed its work. This can happen long after methodA finished execution.

Comment: oh... thanks. Is there anyway of fixing this?  Since I want to return a list of ObjectA when method A completes :)

Comment: @Rosie: Accepting an answer before your problem is solved is not a good idea, because it discourages people from further helping you...

Comment: Oh, you are right.thanks for pointing that out :) Ive tried multiple ways of implementing it, none of them seems to work. Would you have any ideas?

Comment: If this is the regular .NET framework, it should work. However if it's Silverlight, this will cause the app to freeze if methodA is called on the UI thread.

Comment: @Phil: This will cause any .NET app to freeze, when it is called on the UI thread. But if the call doesn't take "long" it shouldn't be a problem. When you reference a web service, by default, all methods are implemented using this async pattern, so this really isn't an indicator for a long running operation.

Comment: @Daniel Well, yes, it will cause any app to freeze temporarily if called on the UI thread. But on Silverlight it will freeze permanently - you'll have to restart the app to get it working. This is because Silverlight uses the UI thread to download data, but the mre.WaitOne() call blocks the UI thread, meaning the download will never start in the first place and it will wait forever.

Comment: @Phil: Are you saying, that the download that happens in the call to `getProductCompleted` is running in the UI thread?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, it happens on the UI thread when non-user code is being executed. As far as I know, this limitation is due to the fact that Silverlight needs to use the browser's networking stack, which, I suppose, is only accessible from the UI thread ("suppose" being the key word). I'm really not an expert in the area, so I could be wrong on some of this. But this is why Silverlight forces you to use an asynchronous programming model.

Answer (score 1):

Your client object has an [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) called getProductCompleted. When that event is published, methodB is executed. client.getProductAsync() is an asynchronous call, meaning it will start downloading a product in the background even though the method will return immediately. When the product is finished downloading, the client publishes the event, causing methodB to be executed.

Comment: Thanks! I realized that methodB only gets called after the service completes, and by then, it is too late, the browser has already finished loading the information.  :(

Answer (score 0):

And there's apparently an error in methodB:

```
 foreach (ServiceReference1.ObjectA obj in products)
    {
        ObjectAtemp = new ObjectA(obj);
         // no temp -- there should be a space between ObjectA and temp in the line above
         // perhaps just a typo here on SO? or in the original code?
         // EDIT: I see the code in methodB has now been corrected.
         _OurObjectA.Add(temp);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. That is from me copying the code. :)